# Exception in thread "main"

Tags: java

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
>       Syntax error on token "]", invalid (

That's the error message I get.
This is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;  //notice javax
public class Frame1 extends JFrame
{
  JPanel pane = new JPanel();
  Frame1() // the frame constructor method
  {
    super("Harry's Random Number Generator"); setBounds(100,100,300,100);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Container con = this.getContentPane(); // inherit main frame
    con.add(pane); // add the panel to frame
    // customize panel here
    // pane.add(someWidget);
    setVisible(true); // display this frame
  }
  public static void main(String args[]) {new Frame1();}
    Random dice = new Random();
    int number;{

    for(int counter=1; counter<10;counter++){
        number = 1+dice.nextInt(1000);
        System.out.println(number + " ");
    }

    }

}
```

Comment: in which line does the error occur? Can you post a complete stack trace please?

Comment: The code you've given us does not contain the error you've posted.  The program runs as shown, though it doesn't do much other than print some numbers and throw a gray frame on the screen.

Comment: You're probably using Eclipse then. Press Alt-Shift-Q and then X (or go to Window - Show view - Problems). You'll find the compilation error messages in this view. Read them, and fix the compilation problem.

Your code would be much more readable, and you'd notice the errors much more easily, if it was indented correctly. Press Ctrl-Shift-F in the editor to format the code.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is completely messed up.

These lines:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {new Frame1();}
    Random dice = new Random();
```

start and end the main method, and then define a *member* variable `dice`.

These lines:

```
int number;{

for(int counter=1; counter<10;counter++){
    number = 1+dice.nextInt(1000);
    System.out.println(number + " ");
}

}
```

then go on and define another member variable `number` and then an *instance initializer* `{ ... }`.

Start by formatting your code properly. Syntactically speaking, I would write it like this:

```
import java.awt.Container;

public class Frame1 extends JFrame {

    JPanel pane = new JPanel();

    Frame1() { // the frame constructor method
        super("Harry's Random Number Generator");
        setBounds(100,100,300,100);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container con = this.getContentPane(); // inherit main frame
        con.add(pane); // add the panel to frame
        // customize panel here
        // pane.add(someWidget);
        setVisible(true); // display this frame
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Frame1();

        Random dice = new Random();
        int number;

        for(int counter=1; counter<10;counter++){
            number = 1+dice.nextInt(1000);
            System.out.println(number + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

(Which actually compiles and runs "fine".)

Comment: This doesn't answer his question, however.

Answer (score 0):

Your main method is one line: new Frame1(); then you close main() and some new code appears: Random dice = ... but is not encapsulated within a method.

Comment: This is true, but it doesn't explain the exception or the compilation that caused the exception.